# Return None until query for django filters

Tags: python, django, database

Hello I was wondering if it's possible to return No Query until search was clicked I used django_filter it works fine, but returns all the objects from the database. I wrote this on a mobile phone access to code example isn't available.

Comment: can you share with  us what you have tried  - you can actually do some coding on a  mobile for example in Azure notebook?

Comment: I am not using azure notebook.

Comment: okay, sorry, I cant help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can [filter the primary queryset](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#filtering-the-primary-qs) and use `.none()` if `request.GET` is empty.

```
class ArticleFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = [...]

    @property
    def qs(self):
        queryset = super(ArticleFilter, self).qs
        if not self.request.GET:
            queryset = queryset.none()
        return queryset
```

Then use your custom filter set in your view.

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for. I will check and get back. Thanks for your input even without a code description.